# Generate a product code with asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net

hello devs am working on a asp.net project and I want to generate a product code dynamically,I don't want to be adding it everytime,so I want the system to create it for me whenever I add a new Product.

here is my product class

```
public class Article
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public Guid FamilleId { get; set; }
    public Guid EmballageGrosId { get; set; }
    public Guid EmballageDetailId { get; set; }
    public int StockMinimal { get; set; }
    public int QuantiteDetail { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public Famille Famille { get; set; }
    public Emballage  EmballageGros  { get; set; }
    public Emballage  EmballageDetail  { get; set; }
}

var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
        var productCode = $"001/{currentYear}";

        var latestProduct = await context.products.OrderByDescending(f => f.Id)
                                                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (latestProduct != null && latestProduct.ProductCode.Contains(currentYear.ToString()))
        {
            var currentProduct = int.Parse(latestProduct.ProductCode.Split("/")[0]) + 1;
            productCode = string.Format("{0:0000}/{1}", currentProduct, currentYear);
        }
```

here am getting  the ProductCode in this format 001/2023 where 2023 is the current Year but I need this format ART-001/2023

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to string interpolation in C#. This gives multiple options to format the string and helps in text as per the needs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

var productCode = $"ART- {ProductCode}/{currentYear}";

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to separate the business logic code so it's easier to test and understand. I would make a product code class like this:

```cs
public class ProductCode
{
    public int RunningNumber {get; set;}
    public int Year {get; set;}

    public static ProductCode Parse(string s)
    {
        // Add some input checking here
        int dashPos = s.IndexOf('-');
        int slashPos = s.IndexOf('/');
        string artString = s.Substring(0, dashPos);
        string numString = s.Substring(dashPos+1, slashPos-dashPos-1);
        string yearString = s.Substring(slashPos+1, s.Length-slashPos-1);
        return new ProductCode { RunningNumber = int.Parse(numString), Year = int.Parse(yearString)};
    }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"ART-{RunningNumber:000}/{Year}";
    }
}
```

The you can write unit tests to check it and write code like this:

```cs
ProductCode newProductCode = null;
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
var latestProduct = await context.products.OrderByDescending(f => f.Id)                                                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
var latestProductCode = ProductCode.Parse(latestProduct.ProductCode);
if (currentYear > latestProductCode.Year)
{
    newProductCode = new ProductCode { RunningNumber = 1, Year = currentYear};
}
else
{
    newProductCode = new ProductCode { RunningNumber = latestProductCode.RunningNumber+1, Year = currentYear};
}
```

Comment: it throws an error length cannot be less than zero

Comment: Not if you pass something like "ART-001/2023". As the comments says, add some input checking. You can't expect stackoverflow to do all the work for you.